# How to group_by without creating a grouping variable?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I need to perform a basic `group_by` / `mutate` operation using an auxiliary grouping variable. For instance:

```
df <- data.frame(
  u = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1),
  v = c(8, 4, 2, 3, 5)
)

df %>%
  group_by(tmp = cumsum(u)) %>%
  mutate(w = cumprod(v)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-tmp)
```

My problem is that if `df` happens to already contain a column named `tmp` I will lose it.

Of course I could choose a very exotic name instead of `tmp` to reduce the likeliness of a collision (or I could even choose something like `strrep("z", max(nchar(names(df))) + 1)` to be sure) but I'd prefer to have a cleaner solution.

In other words, I'm looking for the `dplyr` equivalent of this `data.table` line:

```
setDT(df)[, w := cumprod(v), by = cumsum(u)]
```

Comment: ```df %>% group_by(cumsum(u)) %>% mutate(w = cumprod(v)) %>% ungroup %>% select(-`cumsum(u)`)```?

Comment: Well there could be a column named `cumsum(u)`. (I agree that it is quite unlikely, but still...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could create a function to take care of this.  Assuming that the temporary grouping variable to be created is 'tmp', by concatenating with the column names of the dataset and calling `make.unique`, if there is already a 'tmp' column in the dataset, the duplicate one will be renamed as 'tmp.1'.  Using the `!!`, naming the column with 'tmp.1' (from `nm1`) will not affect the 'tmp' already present in the dataset.  In case, if there is no 'tmp', column, the grouping column will be named as 'tmp' and later removed with `select`

```
f1 <- function(dat, grpCol, Col) {
  grpCol <- enquo(grpCol)
  Col <- enquo(Col)

 changeCol <- "tmp"
 nm1 <-  tail(make.unique(c(names(dat), changeCol)), 1)
 dat %>%
    group_by(!! (nm1) := cumsum(!! grpCol)) %>%
    mutate(w = cumprod(!!Col)) %>%
     ungroup %>%
     select(-one_of(nm1)) 


}
```

-run the function

```
f1(df, u, v)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#      u     v     w
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  0     8.00  8.00
#2  0     4.00 32.0 
#3  1.00  2.00  2.00
#4  0     3.00  6.00
#5  1.00  5.00  5.00


 f1(df %>% mutate(tmp = 1), u, v) #create a 'tmp' column in dataset
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#      u     v   tmp     w
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  0     8.00  1.00  8.00
#2  0     4.00  1.00 32.0 
#3  1.00  2.00  1.00  2.00
#4  0     3.00  1.00  6.00
#5  1.00  5.00  1.00  5.00
```

---

As a followup (comments from @Frank) about passing expressions

```
expr <- quos(tmp = cumsum(u), w = cumprod(v))
#additional checks outside the function
names(expr)[1] <- if(names(expr)[1] %in% names(df)) 
             strrep(names(expr)[1], 2) else names(expr)[1]


f2 <- function(dat, exprs ){

dat %>%
    group_by(!!! exprs[1]) %>%
    mutate(!!! exprs[2])

}

f2(df, expr)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups: tmp [3]
#      u     v   tmp     w
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> 
#1  0     8.00  0     8.00
#2  0     4.00  0    32.0 
#3  1.00  2.00  1.00  2.00
#4  0     3.00  1.00  6.00
#5  1.00  5.00  2.00  5.00
```

Comment: Hm, I wonder could you generalize to a function that supports an arbitrary pair of expressions for the mutate and group_by as in data.table's `j` and `by=`, respectively? (This function is specific to cumsum of a column and cumprod of another.) I don't know rlang well enough to have any idea where to start, but it would be educational to see, anyway.

Comment: Yeah to write expressions, so one can call `f(DT, grp_expr = list(cumsum(x)), mutate_expr = list (w = cumprod(y))` or something. Seems burdensome to have to write a function for the special case of cumsum + cumprod and then again for all the other cases. (Dunno if that's the best rlang can do or not...)

Comment: @Frank May be `f1(df, u, v, "cumsum", "cumprod")` and changing to `get(fn1)` and `get(fn2)`

Comment: @Frank Inspired from your thoughts, I added an option

Answer (score 3):

You could use `ave` instead:

```
df %>% mutate(w = ave(v, cumsum(u), FUN = cumprod))
```

`by` would also work:

```
df %>% 
   by(cumsum(.$u), mutate, w = cumprod(v)) %>% 
   unclass %>% 
   bind_rows
```